# NullPointerException while creating activity

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

> this is my codes LoginActivity.java file

```
 package com.example.crims;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

TextView screen;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    screen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link_to_register);
     // Listening to register new account link
    screen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Switching to Register screen
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
 }
}
```

> this is my code for 'activity_login.xml' file

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 tools:context=".LoginActivity" >

 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>`
```

> And Finally this is my menifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.crims"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.crims.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity"
              android:label="Register New Account">

    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

> All of these files are here and i want to find my error as I m new to android app development...

Comment: Do you have 

    TextView registerScreen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link_to_register);

in your layout.

Comment: @URAndroid in which layout sir, and how can i induce it in my layout.

Comment: You should first read API guides for android devs... http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html Here is it about widgets, but I would recommend start reading from the beginning: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/index.html

Answer (score 2):

You have `NullPointerException`(NPE) here:

```
10-01 21:02:07.580: E/AndroidRuntime(1299):
   at com.example.crims.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:17)
```

So, check line 17 of LoginActivity.java (you can just double click on this message in the logcat view and you will be navigated to this line).

It seems, line 17 is this:

```
registerScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

As this is NPE, `registerScreen` is `null`. So, you should inspect why it is null. This is because Activity can't find it in line above and it returns `null` instead:

```
TextView registerScreen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link_to_register);
```

This can be one of two possibilities: either you do not have widget with id 'link_to_register' in activity_login.xml, or something other is wrong :)

Check this please and show your `activity_login.xml` file, please.

Comment: here is my activity_login.xml file sir:

Comment: Sir, i have no widget with id 'link_to-register in activity_login.xml file, how can i put it into my xml file.

Comment: i m new to stackoverflow as well and how can i show u my 'activity_login.xml' file as i cann't put it in comment box

Comment: @maiz You could simply edit your question, and include your .xml below the original question... But for what reason did you completely deleted all original question? In current view this question is very poor and is not clearly known what is asked there :) In this way nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: I have provided all files u required to solve my question, especially my activity_login.xml and manifest file are also added here.

Answer (score 0):

Listen brother take this code. Change it according to you.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView screen;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    screen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.screen);

            // Listening to register new account link
           screen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Switching to Register screen
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Register.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    } 


}
```

You need to register your activity in manifest.xml file too in case if you don't know about it.

Comment: I have register it already, u can view it in my manifest file i have provided now

Comment: ok.. i have edited some code. try to write the same code in new project. If you are working on eclipse IDE then sometimesthese problems occurs. cross check your api level and the emulator on which you are running.